# (Android + Firebase) Automatically sending push notifications on child added

Tags: android, database, firebase, notifications, chat

So I'm trying to make a group chat for an Android app using Firebase. What I want to do is send automatic notifications to users whenever a child is added to the realtime database (i.e when someone else sends a message to the group chat I want the other users to get a notification, regardless of if the app is in the forground or not).

Does anyone have any experience doing this? I have been looking around and I haven't found any good answers. Not even sure it can be done using firebase.

Comment: Sending FCM messages when a database record changes requires that you run some code that always listens for those changes. See this blog post for an example of how to do that: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/39670667/how-to-push-notification-to-client-when-firebase-has-a-new-entry/39671650